# Circular Progress Bar Android

Tags: android, progress-bar

Galera, to tendo problema de como fazer um circular progress bar, alguém teria como me explicar e mostrar algum exemplo?. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Qual problema você está tendo ?

Comment: Não estou tendo nenhum problema, só queria saber como faz. Preciso q apareça um quando aperto um botão para tirar foto de vários itens dentro de uma listView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode seguir esse exemplo para criar um progress bar circular:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/how-to-create-circular-progressbar-in-android

Obrigado